# Apache 2.4 RPAFsethostname equivalent

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-rpaf

We had a 2.2 server running with mod_rpaf with configuration directives like this:

```
LoadModule rpaf_module modules/mod_rpaf-2.0.so
RPAFenable On
RPAFsethostname On
RPAFheader X-Forwarded-For
```

Now with 2.4, it seems we do something like this

```
LoadModule remoteip_module moudles/mod_remoteip.so
RemoteIPHeader X-Forwarded-For
RemoteIPTrustedProxy 10.0.0.0/24
```

*(note please feel free to correct my syntax if wrong)*

But where is the equivalent to **RPAFsethostname**?